# How to create channel with discordgo

Tags: go, discord, discordgo

I want to make a bot create a channel on discord.

I have made a connection with the discord token:

```
// Create a new Discord session using the provided bot token.
dg, err := discordgo.New("Bot " + Token)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error creating Discord session,", err)
    return
}

// Register the channelCreate func as a callback for ChannelCreate events.
dg.AddHandler(channelCreate)

// Open a websocket connection to Discord and begin listening.
err = dg.Open()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error opening connection,", err)
    return
 }
}

// channel is create
func channelCreate(s *discordgo.Session, event *discordgo.ChannelCreate ) {

     // create channel here
}
```

How to use the **ChannelCreate** type on https://gowalker.org/github.com/jonas747/discordgo#ChannelCreate

Comment: it seems like bot can create only guild channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`discordgo.MessageCreate` is the channel created event. Meaning the handler will trigger when a channel is created. I'm not sure what are the conditions you want your bot to create a channel. Let's say you want to create a channel by messaging the bot. You will first need to add a handler on the message event

```
func messageCreate(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.MessageCreate) {

    // Ignore all messages created by the bot itself
    if m.Author.ID == s.State.User.ID {
        return
    }

    if m.Content == "create channel" {
        s.GuildChannelCreate(guildID, name, type)
    }
}
```

With the type being one of the following:

```
// Block contains known ChannelType values
const (
    ChannelTypeGuildText ChannelType = iota
    ChannelTypeDM
    ChannelTypeGuildVoice
    ChannelTypeGroupDM
    ChannelTypeGuildCategory
    ChannelTypeGuildNews
    ChannelTypeGuildStore
)
```